# Delete same objects from an array as another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects `array 1` and `array 2`, I want to remove the objects of `array 2` from `array 1`. There can be more than 1 objects that I remove simultaneously.

**Data of array 1**

```
let arr1 = [    
    { id: "1", txt: "first"},
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
    { id: "3", txt: "third"}
 ]
```

**Data of array 2**

```
let arr2 = [
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
]
```

**Result**

```
{ id: "1", txt: "first"},
{ id: "3", txt: "third"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id` property is unique, you can filter out with it.

```js
let arr1 = [    
    { id: "1", txt: "first"},
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
    { id: "3", txt: "third"}
 ]

let arr2 = [
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
]

let arr3 = arr1.filter(e1 => !arr2.some(e2 => e2.id === e1.id));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: I would use `arr2.some` since it returns a boolean, although the outcome is the same

Comment: @HaoWu I Agree. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to do a *deep equality check* between the objects, then we can use lodash's `isEqual` to do a deep equality check along with `Array#filter` and `Array#some`:

```js
let arr1 = [    
    { id: "1", txt: "first"},
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
    { id: "3", txt: "third"}
 ]

let arr2 = [
    { id: "2", txt: "second"},
]

const filterArr = (arr1, arr2) =>{
  return arr1.filter(a1 => !arr2.some(a2 => _.isEqual(a1, a2)))
}
console.log(filterArr(arr1, arr2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```